# Get number of the current step

Tags: github-actions

For troubleshooting purposes, I would like to obtain the URL to the current step of GitHub Actions logs.

The URL seems fairly easy to calculate:

```sh
url="https://github.com/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY/runs/$GITHUB_RUN_ID?check_suite_focus=true#step:$step_number:1"
```

What's missing is getting the number of the current step - I don't see it listed on https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts or https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables. Hard-coding the number is not ideal as adding/removing steps before this one will result in wrong/misleading URLs.

Is there perhaps some way to get the current step number that I've overlooked?

Alternatively, the step can have an `id`. However, it doesn't seem like there's a way to link to a step's log section by its `id`, is there?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there perhaps some way to get the current step number that I've overlooked?

Here is one (very) ugly way:

1. Give **all** steps an `id`. This causes them to be added to the `steps` object.
2. Obtain the length of the `steps` object with `jq`:

   ```sh
   step_nr=$(echo '${{ toJson(steps) }}' | jq length)
   ```
3. Add 2, to get the 1-based step number. (+1 to convert 0-based numbering of length of steps so far to 1-based numbering used by the URL hash parser, and +1 for the "Set up job" step that runs automatically.)

---

> Alternatively, the step can have an `id`. However, it doesn't seem like there's a way to link to a step's log section by its `id`, is there?

Looking at the JS code which handles the hash part of the URL, there is:

```js
const e = window.location.hash.match(/^#step:(\d+):(\d+)$/) || [];
```

So, "no" apparently, at least not via the same mechanism as for indicating the step ID by number.